# Hibernate throws expection, attempts to read non-updatable field before saveAndFlush

Tags: hibernate

Relevant part of the entity (without the getters/setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userresults")
public class UserResultObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userresult_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "userresult_username")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "userresult_score")
    private Long totalScore;
    @Column(name = "gamename", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String gameName;
```

My repository:

```
public interface UserResultRepository  extends JpaRepository<UserResultObject, Long>
```

Here's how I use it:

```
    UserResultObject exactResult = userresultRepo.findExactScore(body.getUserName());
    if (exactResult == null) {
        exactResult = new UserResultObject();
        exactResult.setUserName(body.getUserName());
        exactResult.setTotalScore(totalScore);
        userresultRepo.saveAndFlush(exactResult);
        return;
    }
    if (exactResult.getTotalScore() != null) {
        totalScore += exactResult.getTotalScore();
    }
    exactResult.setTotalScore(totalScore);
    userresultRepo.saveAndFlush(exactResult);
```

The "findExactScore" is a native SQL query, which results only one row, and it returns NULL for the gamename ("NULL as gamename") field.

The insert works fine, but before the update, hibernate trows an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'userresult0_.gamename' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
```

What I see is that Hibernate reads the record before saving it, and adds the non-updatable column to the select:

```
select userresult0_.userresult_id as userr1_59_0_, userresult0_.userresult_username as userr2_59_0_,   userresult0_.userresult_score as userr3_59_0_, userresult0_.gamename as gamename4_59_0_ from userresults userresult0_ where userresult0_.userresult_id=?
```

There must be something I miss, only I do not know what it would be.

Note: "gamename" comes from another table in some of my queries.

I use mySQL.

I did try to use the SelectBeforeUpdate, added it after the @Entity annotation:

@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)

I did try to use the @SelectBeforeUpdate(value=false) too, although IMO there shouldn't be a difference.

As it is shown in the code, I want my database record updated with the new total score.